# Can I make an update trigger using data from one table to update another?

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to get the suspension value in my studentstaff table to change from 'no' to 'yes' when the fine (a separate table) amount reaches >=10 for a specific person. I've also tried using IF but nothings seems to be working as I keep getting this error: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification. "amount NUMBER(8);" is in the code as it was asking me to declare amount. I am using Oracle SQL. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_suspension
AFTER UPDATE ON fine
FOR EACH ROW
    amount NUMBER(8);
BEGIN
CASE
WHEN Amount >= 10 THEN
UPDATE studentstaff
SET suspensions = 'yes'
WHERE library_card_no = '419746';
END CASE;
END;
/
```

Comment: In order to reference the `amount` from the row that changed you need to use `:old.amount` or `:new.amount`. Does that `library_card_no` filter also need to be taken from your trigger row?

Comment: @AndrewSayer library_card_no refers to the specific persons' suspension status I want to change but I suppose its not necessary. I'm pretty new with SQL but from what I can gather I ought to use :new like this.
`CREATE TRIGGER new_suspension
AFTER UPDATE ON fine
FOR EACH ROW
    amount NUMBER(8);
BEGIN
CASE
WHEN (new.Amount >= 10) THEN
UPDATE studentstaff
SET suspensions = 'yes';
END CASE;
END;
/
`
But i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for this type of `trigger` is to use the `when` condition on `trigger` as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_suspension
AFTER UPDATE ON fine
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.AMOUNY >= 10)
BEGIN
   UPDATE studentstaff
   SET suspensions = 'yes'
   WHERE library_card_no = :new.LIBRARY_CARD_HOLDER;
END;
/
```

This `trigger` will be executed when the condition written in the `WHEN` clause is satisfied.

Comment: THIS IS THE ONE! Thank you so much! I ended up deleteing `WHERE library_card_no = :new.LIBRARY_CARD_HOLDER;` as yeah i figured it was redundant. Many thanks again stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table definitions its hard, but here's a guess at what you might need

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER new_suspension
AFTER UPDATE ON fine
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if :new.Amount >= 10 THEN  -- ie, the incoming AMOUNT on the FINE table
   UPDATE studentstaff
   SET suspensions = 'yes'
   WHERE library_card_no = :new.LIBRARY_CARD_HOLDER -- ie, the STUDENT being fined
 end if;
END;
/
```

Hopefully that makes sense and is close to what you're aiming to achieve here.  In this example, I'm assuming that your FINE table, contains the amount and the library card holder (ie, the student etc)